# Find the "potential" cyclic reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We have a big solution(320 projects, 2.5 million LoC to give an idea).

I'm trying to add a reference from a project to another project, but VS doesn't allow me to do it because it would imply having a cyclic reference.

I fully understand what a cylcic reference is, and I know how to find them in small solution, but here, there is no "direct link" between the two project(and I also check with one more intermediary project).

But to check that it already took me a very long time.

What would you do to find the whole "chain" of projects(or all the chains of projects) that would imply a cyclic dependency.

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't really change the question but you seem to be missing some form of multiplier in your first paragraph (it does amuse me to think of a solution composed of over 300 projects that, overall, contain *nearly* 3 lines of code)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ahah totally correct, fixed

Answer (score 3):

Would viewing the project dependency diagram visually help?

Right click your solution in Solution Explorer, then click 'View project dependency diagram'

Make sure you have the 'Show Transitive references" option enabled, this will show you where you have indirect dependencies, which might be the issue.

Comment: I've just realised this is a Resharper tool. I fyou dont have Resharper, @user3185569's option should give you a similar view

Comment: I've resharper :) I'm currently generating the chart, I hope it will readable with that number of projects ;) )

Comment: For now, When I try to export to PNG(because it ram when I try to navigate on it, unusable) I got PNG with 0Bytes :( )

Comment: How would you do to find the references that prevent me to add another one due to Prevent references? Because In my case, with all those projects, it's really hard to see anything(and resharper takes a lot of time for any upgrade). Also in my case, the option is named "Show Project Dependency diagram", is it correct?

Comment: I tried to do a right-click, then "Show This and dependant", on the library in which I try to add a reference. I was expecting to see the reference as a dependance at some point, but not the case for now, even there is several levels I did checked.

Answer (score 1):

I ended by doing my own tool to find the result. Since I did loose quite some time on this I decided to publish it: https://github.com/jgrossrieder/CyclicReferenceFinder

Answer (score 0):

I think the Visual Studio team should add more information to the classical Cyclic Reference Error.

### Visual Studio Ultimate Version Solution:

Follow this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to create a visual Dependency Diagram which also helps you identify potential problems in your solution and dependencies.

### How do I get started?

> Get an overview of your solution: On the Architecture menu, choose
>   Generate Dependency Graph, For Solution. You get a graph that shows
>   the top-level assemblies. You can now explore these assemblies by
>   expanding them. Move the mouse pointer on top of an assembly, and then
>   choose the chevron (^) button when it appears. Do the same for
>   namespaces, types, and members to continue exploring your code.

[image]

This requires VS Ultimate Version.

### Free Alternative:

A Free Alternative can be found [Here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b11824d0-d942-4863-99f8-e1884f26387a)

[image]

### PowerShell Alternative:

You might also wan to take a lot at this interesting [Power shell](https://blog.dantup.com/2012/05/free-dependency-graph-generation-using-powershell-and-yuml/) script by "Danny Tuppeny" that gives this result:

[image]

Script from page:

```
function Get-ProjectReferences
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$rootFolder,
        [string[]]$excludeProjectsContaining
    )
    dir $rootFolder -Filter *.csproj -Recurse |
        # Exclude any files matching our rules
        where { $excludeProjectsContaining -notlike "*$($_.BaseName)*" } |
        Select-References
}
function Select-References
{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$project,
        [string[]]$excludeProjectsContaining
    )
    process
    {
        $projectName = $_.BaseName
        [xml]$projectXml = Get-Content $_.FullName
        $ns = @{ defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" }
        $projectXml |
            # Find the references xml nodes
            Select-Xml '//defaultNamespace:ProjectReference/defaultNamespace:Name' -Namespace $ns |
            # Get the node values
            foreach { $_.node.InnerText } |
            # Exclude any references pointing to projects that match our rules
            where { $excludeProjectsContaining -notlike "*$_*" } |
            # Output in yuml.me format
            foreach { "[" + $projectName + "] -> [" + $_ + "]" }
    }
}
$excludedProjects = "Test1", "Test2"
Get-ProjectReferences "C:\Users\DanTup\Documents\MyProject" -excludeProjectsContaining $excludedProjects | Out-File "C:\Users\DanTup\Documents\MyProject\References.txt"
```

Comment: This does require Ultimate/Enterprise edition of VS, however.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever free alternative added.

Comment: @user3185569 Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I've "only" the enterprise version. I wanted to try your alternative version, but it doesn't seems to be compatible with VS2015(I got an error message saying this is not applicable to any installed product). I've to get some more information for the PowerShell, I'm not really aware of how it works(how I should make it works)

Comment: @user3185569 I just tested your powershell script, for a unknown reason, it stops at the first level of dependencies. The path you give should be the path were all projects are located, or the subfolder with my specific project?

Comment: @J4N in windows. `Start => Run => Power shell` => Copy and paste the script but change the 2 paths to your local project path. Then paste the `References.txt` file results to `http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw`

Comment: @J4N i just tried it on my machine and it works. Give it the root folder where `.sln` is.

Comment: I was doing it for one specific project, now with the root, it works. But once I pasted it on the site and asked for generation, it still pending, I guess due to the size

Comment: @J4N It may take time based on the size.

Comment: @user3185569 I undestand that, But honestly after 3hours and results, I don't have much hope